# Spark view engine & MVC.NET 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine

Does anyone know if [Spark](http://sparkviewengine.com/) will be making the transition across to MVC.NET 4?

I have taken a look at the public branches on the [repo](https://github.com/loudej/spark/branches) but nothing there suggests any effort, also there has been no active commits since back in February.

If so... any ideas how far away it will be?

Thanks

Comment: This you have to ask in the Spark community

Comment: I think you were looking at the wrong spark repository.  [This](https://github.com/SparkViewEngine/spark/commits/master) looks more like the right place and appears to be under somewhat active development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update** : This has now been released thanks to the efforts of a [kind contributor](https://github.com/SparkViewEngine/spark/pull/39)

Find it here --> http://nuget.org/packages/Spark.Web.Mvc4

---

The reason it hasn't been done yet is that we're not seeing any demand for Spark in ASP.NET MVC 4 since Razor arrived. Razor is tightly coupled with MVC and the tooling support so much so that, being the default, it completely wiped out any competition.

We're seeing much more demand in the alternate framework space like NancyFX, FubuMVC and ServiceStack to name a few so we're concentrating most of our limited resources there.

If support for MVC 4 is something you'd like to see and are prepared to help get it there, please do get in touch as I'd like to help, but my time stretched as it is on many other projects wanting Spark integration as well.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and sorry for the slow response to mark it as the appropriate answer... cheers